# Sitecore detect an Item saving is in EventDisabler() context

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sitecore, sitecore6

In my sitecore web application OnItemSaved event I want to detect whether the item is being saved under EventDisabler context or not. For an example, an item is edited as shown in below...

```
using (new EventDisabler())
{
    item.Editing.BeginEdit();
    // do edits
    item.Editing.EndEdit();
}
```

In the below method I want to identify the item is edited in an EventDisabler context.

```
protected void OnItemSaved(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
     // detect EventDisabler() context
}
```

Also an item can be saved as `item.Editing.EndEdit(true);` I guess which means interanlly use EventDisabler context. In which way the it is applied I just want to detect the EventDisabler(). How can I detect the EventDisabler()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a static property `IsActive` in `EventDisabler` class:

```
EventDisabler.IsActive
```

This will return `true` every time you are in `EventDisabler` context.

You need to remember that when you're in `EventDisabler` active context, `item:saved` event won't be called (same when you call `item.Editing.EndEdit(true)`.

You can check the `EventDisable.IsActive` state in `item:saving` and it will let you know the state of `EventDisabler`, but checking this in `item:saved` event (as [Mark Cassidy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/81631/mark-cassidy) noticed) is pointless.

Comment: Very Zen-like... while probably true, I'm not convinced that checking for the EventDisabler.Active inside an OnItemSaved _event_ makes any sense however :-)   As far as I am aware, OnItemSaved would never get called with events inactive.

Comment: using (new Sitecore.Data.Events.EventDisabler())
    using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
    {
 ....
 item.Editing.EndEdit();
    }


But in the OnItemSaved event, `EventDisabler.IsActive` is false. I also tried swapping the two using statements as well.

Comment: @MarkCassidy you're absolutely right. `item:saved` event is not called when `EventDisabler` is enabled. Answer updated.